# Take values from json and store in list

Tags: python, json

How to store values in list from json in python. Example

```
**test.json**
{
  "keyword":[
  {
    "name": "Shakti",
    "jobRequisition": "156235",
    "listofKeyWord": {
      "name": "JavaScript",
      "mandatory": false
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Pavan",
    "jobRequisition": "652378",
    "listofKeyWord":
      {
        "name": "Java",
        "mandatory": true
      }
  },
  {
    "name": "Manali",
    "jobRequisition": "872347",
    "listofKeyWord": {
      "name": "Python",
      "mandatory": false
    }
  }
]
}
```

--Python Code--
I want read name and mandatory elements from above json and store in

```
mandatory_list = []
optional_list = []
```

example: for 1st object

```
  "listofKeyWord": {
      "name": "JavaScript",
      "mandatory": false
    }
```

how to check if value for key **mandatory** is **false** the name
**JavaScript** should go in **optional_list** variable and if **mandatory** is **true** it should go in **mandatory_list** variable.

Final output based on above Json:

**optional_list = ['Javascript','Python']**

**mandatory_list = ['Java']**

Answer (score 2):

You can use json library.

```py
import json

f = open('data.json')
data = json.load(f)
```

then your Keyword value will be a list, so you can proceed normally as you would with a list.

Concerning your task:

```
mandatory_list = []
optional_list = []

for keyword in data['keyword']:
    listOfKeyword = keyword['listofKeyWord']
    mandatory = listOfKeyword['mandatory']
    if(mandatory):
        mandatory_list.append(listOfKeyword['name'])
    else:
        optional_list.append(listOfKeyword['name'])
```

And the output is:

```
mandatory_list ['Java']
optional_list ['JavaScript', 'Python']
```

Guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/